# C++ map assignment overload for different types

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, overloading, unordered-map

I have a custom class that inherits from unordered_map like this:

```
class _map : public unordered_map<string, _pointer> {
    public:
    // STUFF ...
};
```

Let's assume that `_pointer` is another custom class that what it does is to help me deal with pointer stuff. `_pointer`s can be constructed from many different predefined types, as an example:

```
vector<...> v;
_pointer p = _pointer(v);
// p is now a _pointer holding v and vector<...> data
```

Now, if I want to store vector<...> `_pointer`s on my map I could just simply do:

```
_map map;
vector<...> v;
map["a_vector"] = _pointer(v);
```

And it works, but I want to be able to do this instead:

```
_map map;
vector<...> v;
map["a_vector"] = v;
```

And have it assigned as a `_pointer(v)` automatically, perhaps by overloading how map assigns stuff and explictly telling it to deal with a `vector<...>` by calling a particular `_pointer` constructor.

I have tried to do that (by overloading operator[], operator=) but it doesn't seem like I'm going somewhere. Can anyone suggest me a way to achieve this behavior?

Thanks.

FAQ:

> Q: Why are you using _ on identifier names? Don't you know that's bad practice?
>   A: It doesn't matter for the issue at hand.
>
> Q: Your code is not RAII.
>   A: So, what?
>
> Q: Why are you not using unique_ptr/smart_ptr? Why are you dealing with pointers directly?
>   A: Because I need to and that also doesn't matter for the issue at hand.
>
> Q: Why are you overloading unordered_map? Why don't you use this _OTHER_OPTION_?
>   A: No thanks, this is what I need to do.

Comment: How about just defining an implicit conversion constructor on `_pointer`?

Comment: Thanks @cdhowie, that sounds like the way to go, but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Any constructor on type A not marked `explicit` and taking exactly one argument of type B will be automatically called when an object of type B is used in a context where an object of type A is needed.

Comment: Wait, how can you do `map["a_vector"] = _pointer(v);` if the map's value type is `_pointer*`? Can we see a sample constructor for `_pointer`?

Comment: @cdhowie How about making that an answer? :P

Comment: @Borgleader I might, but Cameron brings up a good point that would prevent that from working at all. Perhaps when OP clarifies that...

Comment: "Why are you overloading unordered_map? -Why don't you use this _OTHER_OPTION_? - No thanks, this is what I need to do."
Someone has to say it: The only somewhat sane reason to publicly derive from an stl container class is to write a quick draft.

Comment: re your FAQ. Deriving from a standard container is always a mistake.

Comment: Thanks @Cameron, and that's my fault yeah, that shouldn't have a * on the declaration.

Comment: Thanks @cdhowie, I already have an implicit constructor, things is that I'm doing a few more things on `_pointer` that I can't put in the constructor, so I actually need a way to overload the assignment operator.

Comment: @almosnow You can't do this with `operator[]` directly, because the only thing it knows about is the key (`string` in this case). It's implemented in STL containers by returning a reference to the element; `a[b] = c` actually means `a.operator[](b) = c`. As you can see there, the `operator[]` has no knowledge of `c` or its type, so even a template `operator[]` wouldn't work because you can't deduce a return type. (You'd have to invoke the operator like `a.operator[]<SomeType>(b) = c`, which is ugly as sin.)

Comment: @almosnow The only ways to implement what you want would be a conversion constructor on `_pointer` as already mentioned, or by having `operator[]` return a proxy type that can be evaluated as a `_pointer` and also has `operator=` overloads (possibly a template) to accept the type(s) you want to be implicitly assignable.

Comment: @cdhowie The latter option is the one I'm exploring right now. Since the question is about to die in a few moments I can't do much more than thank you for your kind help. Best :D

Comment: @almosnow I've added an answer that provides a bit more detail on the proxy object approach.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There isn't a completely straightforward way to do this by overloading `operator[]` alone.  Let me explain why.

Saying `a[b] = c;` when `a` is of a type with an overloaded `operator[]` is equivalent to saying `a.operator[](b) = c;`.  Note that the operator has no knowledge of `c`, nor its type. In a typical standard library container, `operator[]` returns a `value_type &`. This allows the assignment syntax, because a reference is an lvalue. All you're doing is assigning a new value to an object that already exists in the container.

It should be clear why you can't reasonably overload `operator[]` to do what you want: you can't overload based on return value, and that's the *only way* that the various `operator[]` overloads would differ, since presumably they all need to take a `string` as an argument.

Even if you tried to implement the operator as `template <typename T> T & operator[](string key);` you would still have a problem, because type deduction doesn't work on return types. You would have to write out `a.operator[]<decltype(c)>(b) = c;` and that's just nasty.

Having said that, there is one option that's a bit hacky, but workable: have your `operator[]` return a proxy object, similar to the approach taken by `std::vector<bool>::operator[]()`.  The proxy type would need to have:

- `operator _pointer *&()` (and `operator _pointer *() const`) so that it could be used in contexts that require a `_pointer *`. (These are *implicit conversion operators*.)
- `proxy_type & operator=(_pointer *)` so that a new value could be directly assigned. (This will allow `a[b] = c` to work on the map when `c` is a `_pointer *`.
- Assignment operators for whatever other types you want to accept.  If you can accept anything, then `template <typename T> proxy_type & operator=(T const &);` for example.  This will take care of the case you are trying to implement currently.
- Possibly `_pointer * operator->()` and `_pointer & operator*()` if you want the proxy type to behave just like a `_pointer *` when it is dereferenced.

Answer (score 0):

Your `_pointer` constructor is sufficient... *if you actually defined one*:

```
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Foo{
    int _ent;
public:
    Foo() : _ent(0) {}
    Foo(int ent) : _ent(ent) {}
    Foo(const vector<int>& ents) : _ent(ents.front()) {}
    void printEnt() const{cout << _ent << ' ';}
};

int main()
{
    map<string, Foo> bar;
    vector<int> v{10, 20, 30, 40, 50};

    bar["blah"] = 13;
    bar["bleck"] = v;

    bar["blah"].printEnt(); // prints 13
    bar["bleck"].printEnt(); // prints 10

    return 0;
}
```

I suspect the problem is that you did not define a constructor that matches the `vector` that you are trying to assign.

If you're trying to make a generic pointer class, AKA C++'s auto-pointers, you'll definitely want to templatize `_pointer`.

Comment: Thank you, but is there a way to do this by overloading the map operators? Because, I need to do some other stuff when calling that assignment.

Comment: @almosnow There is not. The map's `operator[]` is going to return a `_pointer&`. The `operator=` is going to be performed on the `_pointer&` **not** on the map. So changing your map's `operator[]` isn't going to change anything. Overriding [`std::unordered_map::emplace`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/emplace/) will give control over the key and value to be assigned. (It should be known that overriding `std` containers at all is a bad idea. But it's not like you haven't been warned.)